# Store javascript functions chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there anyway to enter a javascript function in the console and have it persist after a page redirects?

I have to fill out a form several times that only differs by one field so I wrote some javascript to do it for me but I have to repaste it in every time it submits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a bookmarklet:

- http://juhukinners.wordpress.com/2009/01/08/how-to-write-a-bookmarklet/

This will allow you to just click a button in chrome to apply your function.

Just create a bookmark that starts with `javascript:` and includes your function, for example:

```
javascript:(function() { alert("Hello, world!"); }());
```

Answer (score 3):

You could always use a javascript bookmarklet. Set the url of the bookmark to your code like the following.

```
javascript:(function(){
    // code...
}());
```

If you find it easier to write it in multiple lines, write it out, then minify it, then make a bookarklet.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but if you press the up arrow key on your keyboard you can go through your previously entered commands